# Validating anonymous functions passed in to my function at runtime, with clojure spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Say I have a function `a` that takes a function (`fn`) as an argument:

`(defn a [f] ....)`.

For the sake of giving a nice error message to the caller, I would at runtime validate the `fn` argument.

Is this possible, and how would I go about this? Can I just at runtime `fdef` this, and then instrument it upon calling, something like:

```
(defn a [f] 
   ;;.... spec f here on the fly, and call f, throw exception if f 
   ;; does not conform to spec
 )
```

Is that wise or does it make sense from a philosophical stand point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I just at runtime fdef this, and then instrument it upon calling [...]

No, because `instrument` takes a symbol, resolves its var, and essentially replaces it with a new function that wraps the original — that's where the work of validating the input arguments is done. In your example you won't have access to the `f` function's "original" symbol, and anonymous functions don't resolve to a var.

You can spec higher-order functions, so you could spec `a` like this:

```
(defn a [f] (f (rand-int)))
(s/fdef a :args (s/cat :f (s/fspec :args (s/cat :x number?))))
(st/instrument `a)
(a inc) ;; => 2
(a str) ;; => "1"
(a (fn [x] (assoc x :foo 'bar))) ;; spec error b/c fn doesn't conform
```

**But...** beware that any function passed as `f` to instrumented `a` will be invoked several times with random inputs! This is how spec determines if the function conforms.

```
(a #(doto % prn inc))
-1
-0.75
...
=> 0.18977464236944408
```

Obviously you wouldn't want to use this with side-effecting or expensive functions. I would only recommend using `instrument` for testing/development. You could also use `s/assert` in your function, but this will still invoke `f` multiple times.

```
(s/def ::f (s/fspec :args (s/cat :x number?)))
(defn a [f]
  (s/assert ::f f)
  (f (rand)))
(s/check-asserts true)
```

> Is that wise or does it make sense from a philosophical stand point?

It really depends on the nature of your program and the possible domain of functions passed as `f`.